# AngularJS - calling a webservice with authentication

Tags: angularjs, web-services, http

I am making a web service call using -

```
$http.get(url)
```

Note - 
1) I am dynamically creating the url with query strings.
2) When i type the url in the address bar, it asks for login credentials.

Question -
1) How to add the login credentials in the url, while i am creating it dynamically? I know this is a not a good idea, is there a better way to deal with this situation?

2) I am getting the data from the $http call. Is it because i have logged in once before and the same session is continuing?

Answer (score 0):

Is it standard HTTP credentials? If so, you can use the config flag

```
withCredentials - {boolean} - whether to set the withCredentials flag on the XHR object. See requests with credentials for more information.
```

Your service:

```
app.service('myService', ['$http', function($http){

    var service = {};

    service.getUrlWithCredentials = function(url){
        return $http(url,
        {
             withCredentials : true
        }
    }

    return serivce;

}])
```

Taken from: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http